# How to get mod_deflate running on Heroku

Tags: apache, heroku

Our app is PHP running on Apache. I'm trying to install mod_deflate, however I get the error:
httpd: Syntax error on line 433 of /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 19 of /app/www/heroku/conf/default.conf: Cannot load /app/www/heroku/ext/mod_deflate.so into server: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /app/www/heroku/ext/mod_deflate.so)

Does anyone know what I need to do to get this working?

This is my default.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/app/www/public"

<Directory "/app/www/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#
# Allow more concurrent connections per dyno
#
ServerLimit 12
MaxClients 12

#
# Enable compression with mod_deflate
#
LoadModule deflate_module /app/www/heroku/ext/mod_deflate.so
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Set compression level
    DeflateCompressionLevel 6

    # Force compression for mangled headers.
    # http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
</IfModule>
```

Comment: How did you setup Apache on Heroku to start with?

Comment: Assuming your app is PHP: You need to create a file called Procfile (contents "web: sh www/heroku/web-boot.sh") in your root, plus a file called index.php (it can contain anything, heroku uses this to detect your app is PPH and then installs Apache automatically). Then create heroku/web-boot.sh with the instructions to set-up apache... probably best if you open a new stack exchange question and i can write it out in full. This comments box isn't really meant for this purpose!

Comment: The solution to my problem was to move to nginx and this buildpack, https://github.com/CHH/heroku-buildpack-php. It seems to work fine with PHP and the buildpack includes gzip for nginx.

Comment: Good to know. Glad you worked it out.